# adding arrow navigation to Jquery AJAX + PHP search engine

Tags: php, html, jquery

I've made a search engine for my database table where the search query gets sent by Jquery AJAX to a file called `search.php`. `Search.php` then sends the result back to the Javascript file where the results are processed and added to `index.php`.

Everything works perfectly except when I try to add arrow key navigation. For example, I want the first item in the search results page to be selected (by appending the class, `red` to it and using `focus()`) when I press the down arrow key, the second result to be selected when I press it again, etc..

Nothing gets selected when I press either the up or down arrow key. I'm testing this in Google Chrome.

index.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="search.css"> 

Start searching: <input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off">
<div id="search_results">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="search.js"></script>
```

javascript file:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

    search_x = $('#search').offset().left;
    search_y = $('#search').offset().top;
    search_height = $('#search').height();
    $('#search_results').css({
        'left': search_x,
        'top': (search_y + search_height + 5)
    });

    //arrow key navigation
    start = -1;
    $(document).on('keydown',document,function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 38){

        if (start == -1){
            start = ($('#search_results ul li a').size() - 1);  
        }else{
            start--;
            if (start < 0){
                start = ($('#search_results ul li a').size() - 1);  
            }
        }
        $('#search_results ul li a').removeClass('red').focus();
        $('#search_results ul li a').eq(start).addClass('red').focus();

        }

        if(e.keyCode == 40){

        if (start == -1){
            start = 0;  
        }else{
            start++;
            if (start > ($('#search_results ul li a').size() - 1)){
                start = 0;  
            }
        }
        $('#search_results ul li a').removeClass('red').focus();
        $('#search_results ul li a').eq(start).addClass('red').focus();


        }
    });

    $('#search').on(
    'keyup keydown',
    function(){
        var search_term = $(this).val();

        $.post(
        'search.php',
        {
        search_term : search_term       

        },function(data){
            if (data == "nothing"){
                $('#search_results').fadeOut();
            } else {
                    $('#search_results').html(data).fadeIn();
                }
        }); 
     });
  });
```

part of the search.php file that sends data to index.php:

```
if (!empty($search_term))
{
        echo '<ul>';
    while ($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($search)){
        echo '<li><a href="#">
        <p><strong>',$results_row['place'],'</strong><br>',$results_row['description'],'</p>
        </a>
        </li>';

    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
        echo "nothing";
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)? No need to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: I'm doing it to learn :D

Comment: @user701510 , I couldn't try your code because I can't set it up locally, so, I just made a arrow navigation enabled list and here's it http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Hi xFortyFourx, thanks for the response. I can make the arrow navigation work without jquery ajax but when I generate an unordered list by getting the result from my database, the arrow key function doesn't work. Btw, your jsfiddle link is just linking "jsfiddle.net" and not the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding some free time to code again, I changed `$(document).on('keydown',document,function(e){
//stuff
});` to `$(document).on('keydown','#search',function(e){
//stuff
});`

The key press event listener was applied to the text field, `#search`. The code seemed to work after making the change.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem may be the `on()` method.

You are attaching the method to the `document` object, which is fine, but then also passing `document` as the second argument to the method. The second argument represents a selector that each event is filtered against to see if that was the element that trigerred the event. The `document` element won't both receive the event and originate the event (unless there are literally no elements on the page!)

try something like:

```
$(document).on("keydown", "#search_results", function() {
    //etc
});
```

So the document will still receive the event, but the handler will only be triggered if the event originated from the results container

Comment: still no luck. The thing is, my arrow key navigation works when I manually type in `<ul> <li>blah</li> <li>blah</li> </ul>` inside of `<div id="search_results">` but not when the list is retrieved with AJAX. I've also noticed that if I press the tab key, the first search result has the focus outline then the focus outline quickly disappears.

Comment: Can you put up a demo page so we can see what's happening? Also, how is the AJAX request coded?

Comment: Ok, so you're using the keyup and keydown events now on the demo page? Maybe try moving the event handling code into the success handler for the AJAX request? The events are only used while the results div exists anyway...

Comment: Well I moved all the arrow navigation code into `.success(function(){})` and it's still not working. Dunno if thats what you wanted me to do. You can check the demo page again to see what I changed.

Comment: looks like the key press event listener has to be applied to the text input field to work. Thanks for the help.